# Alternatives to Visual Studio Shell (Isolated)

Tags: visual-studio, shell, vs-extensibility

Many years ago my team started using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) for an application. Over the years, we have updated the application to use the 2012 and 2015 shells. Now, since Microsoft has decided to discontinue releasing Visual Studio shells, I am concerned that eventually we will not be able to install the 2015 shell on future Windows OS releases, and our product will be "dead in the water".
Is anybody aware of a similar product on the market that would serve the same purpose as the VS Shell that could be used instead? Obviously, I would expect it to take a lot of work to migrate our application to a new shell.
I found that Intel has a Fortran compiler that used the isolated shell, and it appears they may have implemented their solution as a VS Extension, requiring users to buy/install Visual Studio itself also. Hoping to avoid that if possible.
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/further-information-on-deprecation-and-removal-of-microsoft-visual-studio-shell-from-ivf.html

Comment: It's 6 years since VS Shell was discontinued, not `now`. The Fortran compiler didn't need to use VS Shell either. It should have been an extension from the start. What is your question though? You're looking for an alternative for *what* ? What are you using the VS Shell for?

Comment: As for what people are using when they want an iDE-like UI over their languages/services/whatever, it's VS Code and [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/). Since it's based on Node, it's cross-platform. It's fast and has a ton of extensions for almost every language. There are extensions for editing and executing Jupyter Notebooks. Azure Data Studio is essentially VS Code for SQL Server. Creating your own language extensions [is documented](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide).

Answer (score 0):

[Actipro](https://www.actiprosoftware.com/) provides controls and a code editor similar to VS shell.